# Can I combine verbs and adjective in a sentence? Example `It is easy to read, edit, remove, and visually appealing.`

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence idiomatic or even grammatically correct?

`It is easy to read, edit, remove, and visually appealing.`

Here I have 3 verbs that are supposed to go with the adjective "easy". "visually appealing" is supposed to go with "It is".

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjunctions join similar entities. The *and* you have there joins two adjective phrases (headed by *easy* and *appealing*), but you need another conjunction in there to join your three infinitives (*read*, *edit* and *remove*):

```
                   (a) read
       (1) easy to (b) edit
                    AND
                   (c) remove
 It is  and

       (2) visually appealing
```

ADDED: As Tᴚoɯɐuo says, it would also be a courtesy to clarify the structure by repeating *is* (or even *It is*), which the reader may have forgotten after going through the *easy* phrase.

Comment: You could also make it easier by flipping it around a bit: `It is visually appealing, and (is) easy to read, edit, and remove.`

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't just verbs, those are **infinitives** (verbs in an infinitive form). **To + a verb** is often an infinitive. There is an implied to in front of each of those words.

Answer (score 0):

Stylistically you would repeat **is**:

> It is easy to read, edit, and remove, and is visually appealing.

Comment: The second *is* is dispensable, but the conjunction you added is not.

Comment: Agreed.    Hence, **stylistically**, and the **and**.

Comment: I would use a semicolon before the second *and*.

Comment: @user178049 Not unless you're going to repeat the subject, too: *. . .; and **it** is visually appealing*.

Comment: @StoneyB Would it be an error if I still use the semicolon? I just find it more tidy with the semicolon.

Comment: @user178049 A semicolon assumes the second clause is independent. Which it isn't, if it begins with _and._ If you're going to use a semicolon, you need to drop the conjunction and put the subject back in: `It is easy to read, edit, and remove; it is visually appealing.` Stylistically, though, that's a mess. It implies that the visual appeal is thoroughly tied to all three of the things listed in the first clause, which it really isn't.